# All my token storages changed to zero after a implementation

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, openzeppelin

I have a ERC20 token deployed using the ERC196 Proxy using open-zeppelin contracts (Initializable, UUPSUpgradeable, OwnableUpgradeable, etc).

The problem is, the last implementation upgrade occurred 480 days ago (version 4.4.1). My team needed to update the code again and I imported the open-zeppelin contracts in remix.ethereum.
I think that open-zeppelin contracts received some updates (version 5.0.0) and some storages changed. Given this, we updated the implementation and all slots were reseted. The owner, totalsupply, proxyUuid, etc. Everything is with 0 value and I can't upgrade it again to the old implementation.

Is there something I can do?